How can I add multiple videos to a single YouTube playlist using a single call to the YouTube Data API?
I have been trying to export my playlist to a new account and since I didn't find a good way to do it. I decided to use a python script and the YouTube data API to do this. Well, it did work to some extent but, it is not efficient.
Here is the code:
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]


def get_authenticated_service():
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)

    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                "client_secret.json", SCOPES
            )
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)

    return build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)


def add_videos_to_playlist(youtube, playlist_id, video_ids):
    for video_id in video_ids:
        try:
            request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
                part="snippet",
                body={
                    "snippet": {
                        "playlistId": playlist_id,
                        "position": 0,
                        "resourceId": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": video_id},
                    }
                },
            )
            response = request.execute()
            print(f"Added video {video_id} to playlist {playlist_id}")
        except HttpError as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            break


def main():
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    youtube = get_authenticated_service()

    playlist_id = "PLAYLIST_ID"
    video_ids = [
        "VIDEO_ID_1",
        "VIDEO_ID_2",
    ]

    add_videos_to_playlist(youtube, playlist_id, video_ids)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here as you can see it calls the API each time it needs to add a video. But what I want to do is specify some video ids and add them to the playlist in one single API call. I tried to look for way to do this online but I didn't find anything that is working for me.
Please can anyone tell me if it is even possible to do this. I would appreciate any other method that can get the job done.
I tried to send an array of video ids but that didn't work at all plus I tried this:
def add_videos_to_playlist(youtube, playlist_id, video_ids):
    batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request()
    for video_id in video_ids:
        request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "playlistId": playlist_id,
                    "position":   
 0,  # You can set the position here if needed
                    "resourceId": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": video_id},
                }
            }
        )
        batch.add(request)
    try:
        batch.execute()
        print(f"Added all videos to playlist {playlist_id}")
    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

This was AI generated and it didn't work. This just added the first video to the playlist.

It seems that YouTube Data API v3 PlaylistItems: insert endpoint only supports adding a single video to a playlist, however maybe you will be interested in consider my Stack Overflow answer 71970181.
